# PHP - execute Java programs -> evaluate returns

Tags: java, php, exec

I just found out how to execute a java method over php.

```
exec('execution line');
```

if "execution line" returns any object, is it possible to use it in php-script like a variable?

Comment: I think it only works with strings

Comment: Yeah Php.net says the same, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll only get the result of a command, ie a string. You'll have to go through an extension (ie [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)) to get more "evolved" data, but probably never as simply as you'd like.

Comment: Well i think that is what i need. Php.net says that it returns the last command line...so if i print my value, it should be possible to get a fine String. Thanks!

Comment: @redstreak: If this answer is correct, consider accepting it by clicking the large green tick mark under the answer's score.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the output from running a Shell command in PHP by using:

```
$output = shell_exec("ls -la");
```

The above example will put the output of "ls -la" into the $output variable.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), you can get the stdout and stderr of the executed command.